# issue with displaymember after binding a list to a Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have an issue with binding a list to a datagridview.
The list contains instances of a custom class whose one of the prop is "Nom".

column is my `Datagridview`'s first column.
It was automatically declared by VS this way in the corrrect part :

```
column = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
```

For any reason, if I call  `column.DisplayMember` AFTER `column.DataSource`, I get a `nullreference` exception.
The same code works fine with a `combobox`. Is there something specific with `datagridviews` that I missed?

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

List<C_Exercice> l = new List<C_Exercice>();
l.Add(new C_Exercice("n", "", "", "", "", DateTime.Now, 1, 1, 5, 0, true));
bs.DataSource = l;

column.DisplayMember = "Nom";    
// -> works fine

column.DataSource = bs;// My_Business.Get_Exercices_List("", "", "", 0, -1, true);

column.DisplayMember = "Nom";
//-> when called again, cause a nullreference exception
```

The second call of `DisplayMember` will cause the following exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: I'm not too sure what is not tying up here.  If I paste the code (with a slight modification) above into a new WinForm app Form's Load event, it works fine.  I have created a test class C_Excercise with a single property called Nom.  Where are you calling the above code from in your application.  Constructor?  Event?  I've tried form load and after the InitializeComponent in the form constructor.

Comment: Additionally any call stacks might be useful.

Comment: Thx for your answer.

Initially, the concerned code was into an event.
I tried to move this code into the form's load  InitializeComponent(). Same nullreference error.

as a test, I made a brand new project and only set a datagridview with a combobox column, I used the same code than in my first post with the same custom class. And in this context it works fine....
So it would seem to point to an issue with the datagridview properties. I did not find anything wrong there though.
I then deleted the datagridview and created a new one (in the program having the issue) and the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Stranger and stranger.
Inside the project causing problem:
I deleted the datagrid causing the isue
I create a new datagridview with a combobox column (named System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.column2).. I tested the concerned code and it works fine.
I then inserted into this datagrid the old combobox column that was causing the issue : System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.column ). I replicated the code causing the issue after InitializeComponent().
The same code works fine with the new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn but still causes a nullreference error with the older control.
Seems to point to an issue with the control declaration or parameters. It all looks similar for what I saw in the properties.

Controls are declared this way:
private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn column2;
private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn column;
They belong to the same datagridview.

Here is the code tested right after InitializeComponent() :

```
   BindingSource bs2 = new BindingSource();
        List<C_Exercice> l2 = new List<C_Exercice>();
        l2.Add(new C_Exercice("n", "", "", "", "", DateTime.Now, 1, 1, 5, 0, true));
        bs2.DataSource = l2;


        column2.DisplayMember = "Nom"; //works fine
        column2.DataSource = bs2;// My_Business.Get_Exercices_List("", "", "", 0, -1, true);
        column2.DisplayMember = "Nom"; //works fine


        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        List<C_Exercice> l = new List<C_Exercice>();
        l.Add(new C_Exercice("n", "", "", "", "", DateTime.Now, 1, 1, 5, 0, true));
        bs.DataSource = l;


        column.DisplayMember = "Nom"; //works fine
        column.DataSource = bs;// My_Business.Get_Exercices_List("", "", "", 0, -1, true);
        column.DisplayMember = "Nom";  //causes the nullreference error
```

Well, I just deleted the control causing the issue and use the new one. It solved my problem.
But if someone has an idea why I had this issue, I ll gladly test it in case the resolution can help someone else facing the same problem.